# N page break object after running add_break method fails

Tags: ms-word, python-docx

I'm a having a problem with the python-docx library. I'm following this [page's example](http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/breaks.html?highlight=page%20break) however it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone provide some assistance?

```
>>> all_runs[0]
<docx.text.Run object at 0x7f49b899c5d0>
>>> play=all_runs[0]
>>> play.add_break(WD_BREAK.PAGE)
>>> play.breaks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Run' object has no attribute 'breaks'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page is part of the design documentation, not as-built documentation (notice the title 'Candidate' protocol). There is no `breaks` property implemented on `Run` as yet.

If you can say a bit about what you're trying to accomplish I may be able to help.

Comment: I want to find out where a new page begins in the document. I've been looking at the docs today but nothing's popped out at me

Comment: This is a good question in its own right. The answer isn't completely a happy one unfortunately, but if you want to ask it as a new question I'll be happy to respond. Just make sure you include a python-docx tag.